# compute regular conditional distribution for the (mean, variance) statistic

Tags: probability, analysis, statistics

Say i have $T: R^k \to R^2$, where $T$ gives the sample mean and sample variance.  I read that $T$ is a sufficient statistic for the family of Guassian probability measures on $R^k$.  You can see this using the fisher neyman factorization theorem, but i thought i'd try to see it directly by computing the family of probability measures in a regular conditional distribution and seeing that it doesn't depend on the parameters of the Gaussian measure on $R^k$. If $$R^k \to R^{k+2}, (x_1,...,x_k) \mapsto x_1,...,x_k, T(x_1,...,x_k)$$ were absolutely continuous, I know i could just integrate its density over the first k variables to get the RCD. But of course that's not the case.